# RSS Keeps Downloading on me

Tags: php, codeigniter, rss, feed

I created an RSS Link today with the help of Code Igniter, and when I go to click on the RSS link, Firefox tries to download the file. The first few times, I downloaded it and made sure there were no errors (there were at first, but now that's sorted). Does anyone know why it keeps trying to download the file, instead of going to the "Add to RSS Reader?" page? Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure it's being served with the correct content type:

```
header('Content-type: application/rss+xml');
```

You could also try text/xml - there seems to be some debate...

Comment: I appreciate it!! That was my current setup. I had it as application/rss+xml, then I switched it to text/xml and it worked. I'm going to see if I run into any more problems, but that did what I wanted it to. Thanks.